# Do Drupal 8 / backbone.js have conflict when using AngularJS on top?

Tags: 8

I've just pulled D8 HEAD for my website and I want to use AngularJS instead of backbone.js to create a web app but realized D8 have already embedded backbone.js on every page.

I can disable modules that depends on it like edit or ckeditor if needed.

Even if I could disable it on a specific custom path I create with my module is still a good alternative for now.

There is also a conflict with Twig and AngularJS double curly braces in Drupal 8.

Comment: The admin toolbar uses backbone, not sure if that's going to affect your decision

Comment: So does it mean I can never use AngularJS in a Drupal 8?

Comment: Well no...I haven't tried it but both should be able to co-exist on the same page, but even if not, you just need to disable the component(s) that use underscore. Do bear in mind D8 is still in dev and modules like Admin Menu (which would provide an alternative) aren't ported yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Backbone.js and AngularJS don't have conflict if used in the same page.

So one can ignore Backbone.js existence and do stuff with AngularJS.

Still there might be better ways doing this in future since D8 is still in development as I post this.

And for curly braces conflict with Twig in AngularJS we can config **interpolateProvider** service [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution but you can use `hook_library_alter(array &$library, $name)` and just set css, js or dependencies of the library to empty arrays(since it's not possible to really just remove the library from the list). Though libraries depending on the one you are altering wll break so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Yea, disabling or removing libraries depending on backbone is definitely not a recommended solution.